# share an object between two apps

Tags: android

I want to send an object between two apps .For instance , you can imagin ,there are two apps which calls app A and app B.App A is running and app B should send an object to app A and after reciving the object by app A , app A shold response that I recive the object .
I study several web site but unfortunately I can't understand many thin ,just I understod , there is a simple way for doing this whit SharedPreferences class. I don't want to use this way becuase I don't want the object to save ...

please guid me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intents for that. Just send an Intent for Activity Z of App A in App B and put your parameters in the Extras bundle.

In Activity Z do the same with the reply for Activity Y of App B.